# Strange navigation behavior in angularjs with ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEOJBp

I can navigate from page 1 to page 2 by this link :       `<a href="#/threadContent">GO</a>`

but couldn't get back from page 2 to page 1 using `<a href="#/home">Back</a>`? I wonder why? The code look flawless for me :

```
<ion-nav-view name="home"></ion-nav-view>
<ion-nav-view name="threadContent"></ion-nav-view>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
  <ion-view name="home">
    <ion-content>
      <h2>Home Page</h2>
      <p>Here is the main route for the app.</p>
      <a href="#/threadContent">GO</a>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="threadContent.html">
  <ion-view  name="threadContent" title="Thread Content">
    <ion-content>
    <a href="#/home">Back</a>
       <h2>Using the app</h2>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis architecto hic officia quasi excepturi sequi deleniti maiores consectetur veritatis sint?</p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

Comment: In your case, you dont need to naming the view for each template. Check this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEbomq ..it works!

Comment: I'm confused now, then what's the naming for? also if I just use one <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view> instead of 2, it work too.. omg im confused.

Comment: yes, myself also confused :) but I did not work on multiple views simultaneously. I will get back here if I get chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not use named views if you don't need it. If I understand correclty what you want, all you need is only one `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` in your page.

You need to name a view only if you want to have states modifying more than one area of your page. See [ui-router docs for more](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

You also have to change your default state to `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');` (not '/home').

Here is a working codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogjRwP

Comment: seem like Im confused btw view and states.. when will be a case when there will be different ion-nav-view needed then?

Comment: View is like a placeholder where you want your content to change. Here is what ui-router says about states "A state corresponds to a "place" in the application in terms of the overall UI and navigation. A state describes (via the controller / template / view properties) what the UI looks like and does at that place.
States often have things in common, and the primary way of factoring out these commonalities in this model is via the state hierarchy, i.e. parent/child states aka nested states."

Comment: Still I m not clear on your statement. our question is why that "home" page not works from "threadcontent" page. but it works reversely (home to threadcontent) ?

Comment: @jpwizer Do you know how could I run a service when user went to page 2? I can't put my service within the $stateprovider.state()..

Comment: @Asik Actually it's not working for more than one reason. First you can only have one ion-nav-view at a time in ionic as it "covers" whole screen. Then when you change to state "threadContent" you are viewing the nav-view called "threadContent" (the other nav-view "home" is "hidden" behind. Then when you hit "back" to change the state to "home" it is configured to change only the "home" view which you don't see, not the "threadContent" that your seeing.

Comment: @Asik To illustrate, while being still wrong, if you add in the 'home' views         `threadContent: {  templateUrl: 'home.html'   }` you'll see home template when hitting 'Back'.

Comment: @mike19911 I am afraid you misunderstand what a service is (or maybe I didn't understand your question). In angular services are singleton you can inject where you need it. If you want to use a service in a given state just inject it in the state controller. For more see: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services